# How to make high performance cluster out of 2 laptops I have at home

Tags: networking, performance, cluster

I have 2 laptops at home. Could someone please suggest some free cluster softwares using which I can make a HPC out of these 2 laptops so that when working on one of the laptop, I can use RAM,CPU of both the laptops, because sometimes when I have been browsing in many tabs for long and softwares and movie, my system gets slow.

Also, does this cluster set-up support applications transparently. I mean after cluster set-up, can any application which I run on a machine gets speeded up or only those applications which the cluster supports.

Also, advise on how to connect these 2 laptops, because cluster set-up needs physical connectivity of these computers.

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](http://superuser.com/questions/245242/how-to-make-high-performance-cluster-out-of-2-laptops-i-have-at-home).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One program can only run on one computer. Some tools can use several threads, but that means threads on the same physical computer.

HPC mostly means you have specially written software that starts several parallel applications on different computers that are programmed to share the results.

Your web browser is not one of those programs. HPC usually is not application transparent - unless the application is programmed that way.

Also, HPC doesnt mean to use the RAM or CPU of the other computer locally to add to the capabilities of your primary computer. You chose your software in a way to benefit from running it on both computers. Usually this means the software doesnt interface with the user.

Comment: So are there any cluster-supporting version of firefox or cluster-supporting version of mpeg player?

Comment: no, not that I am aware of

Comment: There are, ut thy cost more than your laptops PER NODE. 2 ford docus dont mak a ferrari. Never.